# CakePHP Containable: Model "Comp" is not associated with model "Comp"

Tags: cakephp, warnings, cakephp-1.3, behavior, containable

I am trying to do a fairly simple CakePHP find using the Containable behavior:

```
$comp = $this->Comp->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Comp.id' => $id),
    'contain' => array(
        'Comp.id' => array(
            'fields' => array('Comp.id'),
        ),
        'Slot' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Slot.start_time',
                'Slot.end_time'
            )
        ),
        'Team'
    )
));
```

...but upon execution a warning is shown:

> Warning (512): Model "Comp" is not
>   associated with model "Comp"
>   [CORE/cake/libs/model/behaviors/containable.php,
>   line 363]

The start of my Comp model is as follows:

```
var $name = 'Comp';
var $hasMany = array('Team', 'Round', 'Match');
var $belongsTo = array('Generation');
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Slot');
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

I am using CakePHP 1.3.6

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$comp = $this->Comp->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Comp.id' => $id),
    'fields'     => array('Comp.id'),
    'contain'    => array(
        'Slot'       => array(
            'fields'     => array(
                'Slot.start_time',
                'Slot.end_time'
            )
        ),
        'Team'
    )
));
```

You told it to `contain` the related `Comp.id`, which means the model `Comp` related to `Comp`, which doesn't exist. You probably meant to simply set the `fields` option of the `Comp` model itself?

Comment: Thanks that works nicely! I didn't think to keep the root model's fields separate.